# onclick event on document.getElementsByClassName is been applied to all the elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, dom, onclick

Please help. I am trying to stop the click event on the play button from applying to all the div at the same time. I want the click event to only apply to the div that's been clicked on. Please see code below for what I have so far. I am using vanilla Javascript.

```
 <style>
                div{
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                    border: 1px solid black;
                }
                .secondview{
                    background-color: blue;
                }
                .firstview{
                    visibility: hidden;
                    background-color: red; 
                }
        </style>
        <div class="secondview">
            <button class="play"> Play </button>
            <div class="firstview"> 
                <p>Play this game </p> 
                <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondview">
            <button id="btn" class="play"> Play </button>
            <div class="firstview"> 
                <p>Play this game </p> 
                <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondview">
            <button class="play"> Play </button>
             <div class="firstview"> 
                <p>Play this game </p> 
                <button id="submit"> Submit </button>
            </div>
        </div>  
    <script>
        var playBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("play");
            for (var i=0; i<playBtn.length; i++){
                playBtn[i].addEventListener("click", showQuestion)
            }
        var question = document.getElementsByClassName("firstview");
            function showQuestion (){
                for(j=0; j<question.length; j++){
                    question[j].style.visibility = "visible";
                }
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: " I am trying to stop the click event on the play button from applying to all the div at the same time" I didn't understand anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do'nt need to iterate all over "firstview" before the callback of the click (question variable is not needed).

You need to get the "firstview" element that is relative to the button that clicked, for each click event.

This is a sample code (enhance this code and verify  null/undefine for every step)

```
function showQuestion (el){
  var view =  el.target.parentElement.getElementsByClassName("firstview")[0];
        view.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Comment: The problem here causing is you use the same class and trigger the event with that class that's why it is happening.

Comment: His problem was different.
you are not triggering event with a class, you are assigning  an event to an element.
Besides, a different class/id for know structure could cause performance issues, and unneeded complexity.

Of course, if you want to distinguish between vies better, you should put id\class in a logic way, and attach event listener to it in the most deterministic way.